# Error: removing the root node of a scene from its scene is not allowed

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error, scenekit

I am getting an error at the last line of the code.

```
- (SCNScene *)getWorkingScene {
    SCNScene *workingSceneView  = self.scene;

    if (workingSceneView == nil){
        workingSceneView = [[SCNScene alloc] init];
        workingSceneView.background.contents = self.skyColor;
        self.scene = workingSceneView;
        self.allowsCameraControl = TRUE;
        self.autoenablesDefaultLighting = TRUE;
        self.showsStatistics = TRUE;
        self.backgroundColor = self.skyColor;
        self.delegate = self;
    }

    return workingSceneView;
}

DPoint *point = [coodinate convertCooridnateTo3DPoint];
NSURL *pathToResource = [NSURL urlWithObjectName:objectName ofType:@"dae"];
NSError *error;
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL:pathToResource options:nil error:&error];
SCNNode *node = scene.rootNode;
node.position = SCNVector3Make(point.x, point.y, point.z);
node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, ((M_PI*point.y)/180.0));
SCNScene *workingScene = self.getWorkingScene;
[workingScene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node can only belong to one scene, much like a view can only have one parent view.

When you call `[workingScene.rootNode addChildNode:node];` you are moving `node` from its current scene (`scene`) to a different scene (`workingScene`). But `node` is the root node of `scene`. You are not allowed to remove the root node of a scene, hence the error.

One solution is to move all of the child nodes of `node` to `workingScene.rootNode`.